# Scalling FlashPunk game for fullscreen

Tags: flash, fullscreen

I'm making a Flash game with FlashPunk. When I press Ctrl+F Flash goes fullscreen but the game stays at the original size, aligned to the top-left corner.

How can I specify to FlashPunk that I want the game scalled to the size of the screen? (keeping aspect ratio, off course)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can [control scaling in OBJECT attributes when you embed the Flash into HTML](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Optional_attributes). Use `scale=default` to scale maintain aspect ratio. When you run the Flash in player, use menu item View->Show All which functions same as `scale=default` in OBJECT in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling your flash movie will decrease performance significantly. I urge you not to do this for any reason. I'm not sure what flash punk is, but try using this:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

Comment: It's a game library: http://flashpunk.net/. Sadly the code you gave me doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the resize event and scale it in code

```
//put this in your initialization method

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize); 
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));


public function onResize(event:Event=null):void
{       

    width = stage.stageWidth;
    height = stage.stageHeight;

    if (scaleX < scaleY)
        scaleY = scaleX;
    else
        scaleX = scaleY;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is to override the setStageProperties public function in your main class (in FlashPunk, your main class should be extending the Engine class)

```
override public function setStageProperties():void 
{
    super.setStageProperties();
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FP class in flashpunk. Specifically `FP.screen.scale` which lets you resize your entire game by a specified factor.  For example, the code below will double the size of your game screen:

`FP.screen.scale = 2;`

If you need to worry about the aspect ratio, you can do X and Y separately with:

```
FP.screen.scaleY = 2;
FP.screen.scaleX = 3;
```

After you go to fullscreen, you can use the code below to get the correct aspect ratio for enlarging your screen:

```
  var scaleFactorX = stage.stageWidth / FP.screen.width;
  var scaleFactorY = stage.stageHeight / FP.screen.height;
  FP.screen.scaleX = scaleFactorX;
  FP.screen.scaleY = scaleFactorY;
```